# convert int array to pointer in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

```
void test()
{
       int buf[1000];

       //populate buf
       foo(buf);//is this correct? Can we pass buf as a pointer that foo expects?



}
void foo(void*ptr)
{}
```

EDIT:
if foo were fwrite, would the above(mechanism of passing buf so as to supply fwrite with content to write into some file) still be applicable?

Comment: do you have a C compiler installed on your system?

Comment: @Vijay: yes I do. Why do you ask?

Comment: After the edit: in most circunstances `buf` decays to a pointer to its first element (`buf` decays to a value of type `int*`). And `void*` is special in that it can be assigned back and forth between pointers to objects. You may like to read section 6 of the [C-FAQ](http://c-faq.com/) ... and the other sections too :)

Comment: Yes, but that's what I want right? Just an int* pointer. will do, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its perfectly valid in C. `foo` argument is a pointer that can point to **any type**. When you pass an array, it decays to a pointer pointing to the first element of the array (i.e.,address location of the first element is passed). So,

```
 ptr -> &buf[0] ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that.

buf is the base pointer of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You will always pass buf to function as a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its correct. You can use the "ptr" pointer in your foo function.
http://codepad.org/HwYd0GAh

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers pointed out, *yes*, you can pass `buf` to the function.

However, inside the function, the variable `ptr` has type `void*`. And there's only a few things you can do with `ptr` itself. Usually you convert it (with or without a cast) to something relevant, like `int*`.

```
void foo(void *ptr) {
    int *iptr;
    iptr = ptr;
    /* now use iptr */
}
```

Comment: Since buf is of type int, won't ptr point to an int array and hence behave as an int pointer?

Comment: @Namratha: as far as the `foo` function is concerned, `buf` does not exist. `ptr` is of type `void*` which means it can "safely" be converted to any other pointer type (*the compiler assumes the programmer knows what he/she is doing*).

Comment: Please check the edited question. Is it true in that case too?

Comment: @Namratha: In that (and most likely any) case, `foo` would need a to know the *size* of the data `ptr` points to. `foo()` should require data as an additional argument, and be called as: `foo(buf, sizeof(buf))`. Or use 2 extra arguments, element size and element count, just like `fwrite()` does: `foo(buf, sizeof(int), 1000)`